# Latex pseudocode template keywords

Tags: algorithmicx, keywords

I a searching for a predefined command for displaying TRUE and FALSE constants in a pseudocode. I tried `\TRUE` `\True` etc. non of them work. I know I could myself use something like `\texbf{...}` but it would be neater to have the right command... Please if you know it, state it here.

I use this template (with the non-existent `\False` to be replaced by ?):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[]{algpseudocode}


\begin{algorithm}
\caption{myproc}\label{proc1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{myproc}{}
\State $x\gets \FALSE $
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard `\TRUE` or `\FALSE` as part of [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx), since it may require different formatting that depend on the pseudocode being written. Define your own `\TRUE` and `\FALSE` using `\algnewcommand` (similar to `\newcommand`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand{\TRUE}{\textbf{true}}
\algnewcommand{\FALSE}{\textbf{false}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My procedure}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{myproc}{}
      \State $x \gets \FALSE $
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```